# Expressão regular quando existe strings iguais

Tags: php, dom, parser

Necessito pegar o valor "R$ 0,00" nessa string com uma expressão regular. Realmente não entendo de expressões, só sei o básico do básico. Existem vários outros valores na página com "R$" seguido do valor, porém não consigo pegar com meus métodos, sempre dá um valor aleatório de outros "R$". Preciso de algo certeiro. OBS: nestas `divs` este é o único valor.

```
<div class="stat-number col-md-12 margin-top-10">
     <div class="title">Programado (Saldo)</div>
     <div class="number">
          R$ 0,00
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pegar com JS? mostre o que ja tentou

Comment: uso a seguinte função para pegar strings:

`function GetStr($string, $start, $end){  
$str = explode($start, $string);  
$str = explode($end, $str[1]);  
return $str[0];  
}`
uso
$estimativa = GetStr($resultado, 'mber">R$','</div ');

Comment: o trabalho dela e pegar o primeiro e ultimo caractere dentre um html para localizar o texto, na maioria das vezes funciona bem, porem com muitas strings iguais e tags iguais não é boa.

Comment: Expressões regulares para pegar informações dentro de um HTML? Você está chamando Ctulhu e não percebe, é por isso que você sente medo no escuro. Regex para pegar coisas do HTML moram em armários e saem quando as luzes estão apagadas para se alimentar do medo das crianças

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o que está procurando seja:

```
<?php 
// Simulando uma string contendo valores aleatórios
$string = "Ola tenho R$ 35.00 e tambem R$ 0.00 com R$ 127335.98 reais";

// Variável onde armazenarei os resultados
$resultado = Array();

// Regra expressão regular
preg_match_all('/(R\$\ [0-9]*.[0-9]{0,2})/', $string, $resultado);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($resultado);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

A saída desse script será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => R$ 35.00
            [1] => R$ 0.00
            [2] => R$ 127335.98
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => R$ 35.00
            [1] => R$ 0.00
            [2] => R$ 127335.98
        )

)
```

Ele retorna 2 vezes o mesmo resultado por que o primeiro índice "0" retorna o FULL MATCH que é a regra estipulada no regex, já os próximos ele retorna o resultado de cada grupo separado da sentença regex (como na minha só tem 1 grupo ele criou apenas 1 índice a mais).